# Remove timestamp string from names of files in folder

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script located in different folder. ( \test remove\ )

I wish to remove 14 characters from all .csv in another folder ( \test remove\remove from here\ ) the folder it removes the characters from could be anywhere (the sub directory is a example)

- little background, the 14 characters is a timestamp (YYYYMMDDHHMMSS), wish to remove the timestamp from .csv files

When I run my script it removes the characters from the folder where the batch script is located.

```
 setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 set removeFileLocation="C:\...\Desktop\test remove\remove from here\"

 for /r %removeFileLocation% %%x in (*.csv) do (
      set "oldname=%%~Nx"
      set "newname=!oldname:~,-14!"
      ren "!oldname!.csv" "!newname!.csv"
 )
```

When running as well I get "The System cannot find the file specified." however it still successfully removes characters from .csv files.

Comment: Just replace `ren "!oldname!.csv" "!newname!.csv"` with `ren "%%~dpx!oldname!.csv" "!newname!.csv"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you try

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "removeFileLocation=C:\...\Desktop\test remove\remove from here"

for /f %%x in (' dir/s/b/a-d "%removeFileLocation%\*.csv" ') do (
  set "oldname=%%~Nx"
  set "newname=!oldname:~,-14!"
  ECHO ren "%%~dpx!oldname!.csv" "!newname!.csv"
)
```

Notes: 
  `set "removeFileLocation...` is changed (1) so that the `"rabbit's ears"` enclose the ENTIRE assignment, which ensures trailing spaces are **NOT** included in the value assigned. (2) the trailing `\` is removed. (this is a matter of personal choice)

The `FOR/F` builds a `DIR` list in memory of the full-filenames only (no headers)

The `ren` needs to have the filenames's drive and path restored.

The `ren` is merely `ECHO`ed to ensure that the operation is correct. Remove the `ECHO` keyword to activate the rename.

What I believe is happening with your original version is that the `for/r` is re-encountering an already-renamed file OR since you've not assigned a pathname to the file to be renamed, it's finding a `.csv` in some subdirectory and attempting to rename it in the current directory, but it doesn't exist there or has already been renamed there.